# React Native Add own view above Modal

Tags: view, react-native

I have the next code

```
import {Navigator, Modal, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
....
....
....
render(){
<View>
  <Modal/>
  <MyView>
</View>
}
```

I want MyView's to be above the Modal one, is that possible?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? If you hide your modal then your view will show above it.

Comment: I don't want to hide my modal, I have a small view(height:30) that I want to be above all other views @LianvanderVyver